# Build groups of two out of a list of people with rating

Tags: algorithm, hungarian-algorithm

I got a list of people and a rating of how good this combination is. I need to maximize the rating. I've already looked at the hungarian algorithm, but it solves a slightly different problem.
How can you solve such a problem?

Comment: "I need to maximize the rating." - the sum of pairs? if so, this has nothing to do with the hungarian algorithm, which works on bipartite graphs.

Comment: Yes, exactly. (Random text to get by the char limit)

Comment: does this answer your question? if not, you have to completely rephrase it.

Comment: Ok, I have rephrased it.

Comment: the hungarian algorithm is the one which works on bipartite graphs ;)

Comment: Oh, so how should I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hungarian algorithm solves a different problem.

You need the [maximum **weight** matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) algorithm for general graphs.

If your graph is small, do a simple (combinatorial) exhaustive search, otherwise implement one of the more complicated [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_general_graphs).